# Как подойти к решению такой задачи?

Tags: c++

> Напишите функцию, которая принимает на вход два числа, 
>   и возвращает сумму всех чисел между ними, которые делятся на 5 или на одно из этих чисел.

В начале пытался что то слепить с циклом, но не знаю. Не получается ничего дельного толком(

хотя бы просто скажите мне какой способ лучше всего использовать :(

Здесь нужно использовать std::count ? 
Или может создать два массива числовых (вот только как, хммм) 
И потом под конец же нужно будет использовать лабда функцию, так ведь ?

Comment: "Пробовал думать по разному" `+1`, "буду примного благодарен" `-1`, `= 0`.

Comment: @Igor мне просто банально не хватает навыков для ее решения. 
Что в принципе справедливо. 
Просто пока у меня такое уродство получалось, что мне просто банально стыдно его здесь показывать (оно ведь даже не работало как нужно)

Comment: `int sum = 0; for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++) if (i % 5 == 0 || i % a == 0) sum += i;`

Comment: @Igor, ещё `i % b`

Comment: @MrBin пропущено, как упражнение для ТС )

Comment: @Igor ТААК ПРОСТО ?????

*angryface.jpg 

<3

Comment: кхм, кхм, чем проще - тем лучше. Конечно, если это просто и *правильно*.

Comment: Только надо не забыть сделать проверку на принимаемые значения, например если `a` или `b` будет 0, будет ошибка, если `a > b`, можно поменять их значения местами.

Comment: Есть такое страшное слово (вернее, два) - *арифметическая прогрессия*...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
int suma(int a, int b) {
 int re = 0;
    for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++) {
        if ((i % 5 == 0) || (i % b == 0) || (i % a == 0)) {
            re += i;
        }
    }
    return re;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90456/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Comment: Брр... ну тогда, если уж посчитать обычную арифметическую прогрессию не судьба,  хотя бы цикл по пятеркам и по `a` (типа `for(int i = 2*a; i < b; i+=a)`...